# Using Merge with a single Create call in FaunaDB is creating two documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, netlify, faunadb

Got a weird bug using FaunaDB with a Node.js running on a Netlify Function.

I am building out a quick proof-of-concept and initially everything worked fine. I had a [Create](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/create?lang=javascript) query that looked like this:

```js
const faunadb = require('faunadb');
const q = faunadb.query;

const CreateFarm = (data) => (
  q.Create(
    q.Collection('farms'),
    { data },
  )
);
```

As I said, everything here works as expected. The trouble began when I tried to start normalizing the data FaunaDB sends back. Specifically, I want to merge the Fauna-generated ID into the `data` object, and send just that back with none of the other metadata.

I am already doing that with other resources, so I wrote a helper query and incorporated it:

```js
const faunadb = require('faunadb');
const q = faunadb.query;

const Normalize = (resource) => (
  q.Merge(
    q.Select(['data'], resource),
    { id: q.Select(['ref', 'id'], resource) },
  )
);

const CreateFarm = (data) => (
  Normalize(
    q.Create(
      q.Collection('farms'),
      { data },
    ),
  )
);
```

This `Normalize` function works as expected everywhere else. It builds the correct merged object with an ID with no weird side effects. However, when used with `CreateFarm` as above, **I end up with *two* identical farms in the DB!!**

I've spent a long time looking at the rest of the app. There is definitely only one `POST` request coming in, and `CreateFarm` is definitely only being called once. My best theory was that since [Merge](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/merge) copies the first resource passed to it, `Create` is somehow getting called twice on the DB. But reordering the `Merge` call does not change anything. I have even tried passing in an empty object first, but I always end up with two identical objects created in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your helper creates an FQL query with two separate `Create` expressions.  Each is evaluated and creates a new Document.  This is not related to the `Merge` function.

```js
Merge(
    Select(['data'], Create(
      Collection('farms'),
      { data },
    )),
    { id: Select(['ref', 'id'], Create(
      Collection('farms'),
      { data },
    )) },
  )
```

Use `Let` to create the document, then `Update` it with the id.  Note that this increases the number of Write Ops required for you application.  It will basically double the cost of creating Documents.  But for what you are trying to do, this is how to do it.

```js
Let(
  {
    newDoc: Create(q.Collection("farms"), { data }),
    id: Select(["ref", "id"], Var("newDoc")),
    data: Select(["data"], Var("newDoc"))
  },
  Update(
    Select(["ref"], Var("newDoc")), 
    {
      data: Merge(
        Var("data"), 
        { id: Var("id") }
      )
    }
  )
)
```

#### Aside: why store id in the document data?

It's not clear why you might need to do this.  Indexes can be created on the ref value themselves.  If your client receives a Ref, then that can be passed into subsequent queries directly.  In my experience, if you need the plain id value directly in an application, transform the Document as close to that point in the application as possible (like using ids as keys for an array of web components).

> There's even a slight Compute advantage for using Ref *values* rather than re-building Ref *expressions* from a Collection name and ID.  The expression `Ref(Collection("farms"), "1234")` counts as 2 FQL functions toward Compute costs, but reusing the Ref *value* returned by queries is free.

Working with GraphQL, the `_id` field is abstracted out for you because working with Document types in GraphQL would be pretty awful.  However, the best practice for FQL queries would be to use the Ref's directly as much as possible.

Don't let me talk in absolute terms, though!  I believe generally that there's a reason for anything.  If you believe you really need to duplicate the ID in the Documents data, then I would be interested in a comment why.

Comment: It's not duplicated actually. All I am sending back to the client is the data object (with the ID merged in). So the client never sees ref/ts. Probably still not best practice, but it made sense in my head.

Comment: It is, actually. `q.Create` does not execute the query, but creates an expression that will create a document. You passed `q.Create` to your `Normalize` function, and then used that value in two places. That means there are two `q.Creates` in the query that gets executed.